# $G$ a group, $H \subseteq G$, $xy^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow$ $H \leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This was a question an exam I had the other day that I didn't quite finish.

It states that $G$ is a group and $H$ is a non-empty subset of $G$ with the property that for any $x,y \in H$ we have that $xy^{-1} \in H$.

I was able to show that indeed $e \in H$ since $xx^{-1} \in H$ and so $ex^{-1}=x^{-1} \in H$.

Now what remains to be shown, I think at least, is that given any $x,y \in H$ then $xy \in H$. I have been trying to come up with a way to express $xy$ in the form of some $zw^{-1}$ for some $z,w \in H$. I have played around with changing $x=ex$ or vice versa and same with $y$ and replacing $e$ with $xx^{-1}$ or $(xy)(xy)^{-1}$ but I haven't quite figured out what I have to use to show this.

Any advice? =/ The exam is over, I will see the solutions eventually but I am curious and want to find out as we do have a part two exam next class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nonempty subset H of group G is subgroup iff $ab^{-1} \in H $ for any $a,b \in H$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291416/nonempty-subset-h-of-group-g-is-subgroup-iff-ab-1-in-h-for-any-a-b-in-h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any $x,y\in H$. You already know that $y^{-1}\in H$. Hence, by the assumption, $xy=x(y^{-1})^{-1}\in H$

Comment: Trivial! Ah well thank you. ;))