# Suppose $H$ is a nonempty subset of a finite group $G$. How to show $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $ab \in H$ for all $a,b \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

One direction follows from the definition of subgroup. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then it must be closed under the operation.

However, if $ab\in H$ for all $a,b \in H$, then it is closed under the operation and thus all we must show is that if $x \in H$, then $x^{-1} \in H$.

Any hints?

Comment: Considering the one-step subgroup test, I think there is something wrong with this question.

Comment: Yeah, a straightforward counterexample consists of the nonnegative integers under addition.

Comment: The usual criterion is $H$ is a subgroup iff $a, b \in H \Longrightarrow ab^{-1} \in H$; maybe there's a typo . . .

Comment: If it's a typo then it is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291416/nonempty-subset-h-of-group-g-is-subgroup-iff-ab-1-in-h-for-any-a-b-in-h?rq=1

Comment: I think it flies as stated if $\vert G \vert < \infty$.

Comment: It’s not true, consider the submonoid $\mathbb N \subset \mathbb Z$. It’s true if $H$ is finite, since $x^{-1} = x^{|H|-1}$.

Comment: @Ben Why not an official answer?

Comment: Sorry guys. $G$ is assumed to be finite. Thanks for the counter when $G$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every $x \in G$; $g$ **finite**; satisfies $x^{|G|} = e$ where $e$ is the identity element [make sure you see why]. So $x^{|G|-1} = x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$. By definition of $H$ (that $a,b \in H$ implies $ab \in H$),  if $x$ is in $H$ then so is every positive power of $x$ in particular $x^{|G|-1} = x^{-1}$ is in $H$. So indeed, every element has its inverse in $H$ too. Thus $H$ satisfies the property of a group.

NOTE: This depends on $G$ being *finite*. For a counterexample with $G$ infinite, suppose $G$ were the set of nonzero rationals (with the operation being multiplication) and $H$ were the natural numbers. Then $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$ even though indeed $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: This proof does not work for infinite groups, and indeed it is false in the case, as the comment of @Ben shows.

Comment: Yes, noted that this does not work for infinite groups--with a counterexample given--just editted after I saw previous comments.