# Nonempty subset $H$ of group $G$ is subgroup iff $a^{-1}b\in H $ for any $a,b \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Subgroup test is given by

Nonempty subset $H$ of group $G$ is subgroup iff $ab^{-1} \in H $ for any $a,b \in H$

But why can't we say Nonempty subset $H$ of group $G$ is subgroup iff $a^{-1}b\in H $ for any $a,b \in H$

(Taking the inverse of the first element).

This is not the duplicate as I didn't ask about the proof, I ask why this particular statement is chosen over other.

> I run through the proof; the same argument can prove this statement, but why almost all the book stated the first one but not second?
>
> Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: There is no reason to choose one over the other.  However, it is easier to follow the proof of a book if they consistently choose $ab^{-1}$ (or consistently choose $a^{-1}b$).

Comment: For doing equivalence of coset, we use $a^{-1}b$, and there $ab^-1$ can't be used. Then why can't we use $a^{-1 }b$in both places, this may even avoid confusion. But since every( by that I mean, all book, I looked at ) book follow the same.

Comment: Thanks, omnomnomnom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonempty subset H of group G is subgroup iff $ab^{-1} \in H $ for any $a,b \in H$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291416/nonempty-subset-h-of-group-g-is-subgroup-iff-ab-1-in-h-for-any-a-b-in-h)

Comment: That is no duplicate, @J.-E.Pin. Look carefully. This question is about why $ab^{-1}$ is favoured over $a^{-1}b$.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate @J.-E. Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is because $ab^{-1}$ is sort of like the "multiplicative difference" between $a$ and $b$, since if the operation is additive, it looks like $a-b\in H$.

So what you are checking is whether for any $a, b\in H$, their difference with respect to the group operation is in $H$.

Hence it makes sense to check $ab^{-1}\in H$, as otherwise it would not be so clear that it is the difference you're checking.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So it's like while studying ring theory, it makes things easier.

Comment: Exactly! Some conventions are there because there is a direct correspondence with what we expect.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind the statement is that you need is to be able to apply the inverse operator to show that $H$ contains the identity, since it contains at least one element $x$ and $xx^{-1}=1$. Once you know this, it follows that $1x^{-1} = x^{-1}$ for any $x \in H$, and so $H$ is closed with respect to the inverse operator. Then it is immediate that it is also closed with respect to the group operation, as $ab=a(b^{-1})^{-1} \in H$.

Since left inverses and right inverses are the same thing in group theory, the two choices are equivalent and there is no particular reason to prefer one to the other.